# When zero stuffing JPEG encoded segments is 0xff byte algined or any consecutive run of bits?

Tags: jpeg, standards, huffman-code

So I understand that the end of encoded segments in JPEG files are padded with 1 bits to align the markers, but what I have been unable to find any clarification for is when dealing with zero stuffing 0xff values inside of encoded segments (Huffman specifically) do we only need to worry about byte aligned 0xff or is it any eight consecutive 1 bits (i.e. with the high nibble of one byte and low nibble in the next)?

The relavent section of ITU-T81 appendix F reads:

> F.1.2.3 Byte stuffing
>   In order to provide code space for marker codes which can be located in the compressed image data without decoding,
>   byte stuffing is used.
>   Whenever, in the course of normal encoding, the byte value X’FF’ is created in the code string, a X’00’ byte is stuffed
>   into the code string.
>   If a X’00’ byte is detected after a X’FF’ byte, the decoder must discard it. If the byte is not zero, a marker has been
>   detected, and shall be interpreted to the extent needed to complete the decoding of the scan.
>   Byte alignment of markers is achieved by padding incomplete bytes with 1-bits. If padding with 1-bits creates a X’FF’
>   value, a zero byte is stuffed before adding the marker.